# How do I write a function for showing only one category?

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I want my wordpress page to show recent posts, with just one category.
I'm new to PHP and wordpress, so please bear with me.

```
$categories = get_the_category();

if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
    echo esc_html( $categories[0]->name );   
}
```

When I past this code into my functions.php, the site crashes.

You can see the site here: http://2016.sv.emil2518.mguro.sde.dk/skatersmag/

Comment: _“the site crashes”_ - meaning the same as the famous “blank page”? Then go enable proper PHP error reporting first of all, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death

Comment: `echo $category[0]->cat_name;` try it

Comment: do `var_dump($categories);` after `$categories = get_the_category();` and show us what you got? (add in your question by editing it)

Comment: @misorude
I mean I get this message: The site is experiencing technical difficulties.

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie
I just tried that. Can you please write the exact function, since I'm really new to this, just to make sure I'm doing it right.

Comment: _“The site is experiencing technical difficulties.”_ - that’s likely just a generic error document for a 500 error, so you need to go and check the server error log to find out what the actual error was.

Answer (score 1):

Send the post id, check haw many categories the post belongs to and return false if there are more than one, and return the category if it is only one.

```
function get_posts_with_only_one_category( $postId ) {
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $postId, 'category' );
    $term = false;

    if( count( $terms ) == 1 ) {
        $term = $terms[0]->name;
    }

    return $term;
}
```

Later when you do the looping through the posts you can check:

```
// loop
$ifOnlyOne = get_posts_with_only_one_category( get_the_ID() );

if( $ifOnlyOne == false ) {
   continue;
}
```